# String to String array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi all I am framing a string as per my requirement

```
var empID=1;
var empName='XYZ';
var vData="ID=" + empID+ ";" + "Name=" + empName+ ";" // here I will read the data from the form on clicking the button the above is sample data
```

I need to convert this to string array I tried using `JSON.parse` but it is giving me some exception as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S`

```
var varray = JSON.parse("[" + vData + "]");
```

So can some one tell me how can I convert my data to an array so that is should be like

```
var items = [
          { ID: 1, Name: xyz },
          { ID: 2, Name: PQR },
    ]
```

Comment: That's not JSON, JSON is a specific format. JSON would look like `"{ID:..,Name:..}"` http://json.org

Comment: You got 2 Options: *Either* be standards compliant with JSON, then you can use `JSON.parse()` *or* use your own format and write your own parser for it!

Comment: Where did you get `2` and `PQR` from?

Comment: 1: JS doesn't have associative arrays, only obejcts and arrays. 2. JSON is an acronym and stands for JavaScript Object Notation. Converting data to JSON in JS will always result in valid JS objects/arrays. Building a string using JS variables, and then passing it to `JSON.parse` is just silly. write the JSON you want _without_ quotes, and you'll have what you need

Answer (score 2):

That's not JSON. Try something like:

```
var vObj = {ID: empID, Name: empName};
var vData = JSON.stringify(vObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this

```
var vdata= {};
vdata["empID"]="9";
vdata["empname"]="empname";
alert(JSON.stringify(vdata));
```

This will give you alert

```
{"empID":"9","empname":"empname"}
```

Comment: i think it is best way to build object structure.